# Why Spring Cloud 2021.0.3 requires additional configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have upgraded Spring Cloud from `Greenwich.SR1` to `2021.0.3` and the application started to fail and shows following description:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'ktable-KafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'ktable-KafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 1000
              default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              default.deserialization.exception.handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
```

I have looked at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html) and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html) to see the configuration properties to see if anything was added in the new version. I am not sure why the error is occurred on the new version (`2021.0.3`) as the application was working fine on `Greenwich.SR1`. In addition,I don't get additional error stack other than the above description.

Comment: Are you using multi-binder configuration in your application? Could you share with us a small application to see what's going on?